# What is a OneNote like document editor that allows writing on the sections as well as pages?

Tags: documentation, microsoft-onenote

I'm looking for some software to write some documentation that is organized in a tree structure. The two closest ones that I have found so far are OneNote and Trilium.

OneNote does not let you write on anything but a page. If you create a group, you cannot put a note on the group itself. The three level hierarchy of OneNote is also an issue, but it can be worked around.

Trilium seems to do the job well, but doesn't use "files". There is no concept of **File->Open**. Your computer just holds one big notebook. If you want to see someone else's book you need to import it into your own book. This is a big issue.

I have tried lots of software already...

- Obsidian
- Treeline
- Scribus
- GitBook
- Keynote NF
- PDF24
- Joplin
  ...and more

What I'm looking for...

- Allows formatting (bold, italic, font, etc.) Codeblocks are a bonus.
- You can put notes on the sections as well as the pages.
- Works offline
- Handles files so one can open a book, close it and open another. Be able to send a copy of the file to someone so they can view it.
- Many layers of sections.
- Tree like organization.
- Ability to print or export the notebook as a PDF is a bonus.

Is there anything like this out there?